# Views are not Removed from TableLayout

Tags: java, android, view

I have linearlayout to which I m adding tablelayout and rows programmatically.

When I m calling a method first time, it works fine and data is showing for given number of rows.

On next call previous rows are still visible and new data is added below to previous data. I tried to use all methods of removing views but still could not get rid from old rows. pls help.

My Table Code:

```
 private void maketripsumtable(String pname) {


        if (((LinearLayout) sumtablelay).getChildCount() > 0) {
            ((LinearLayout) sumtablelay).removeAllViews();
            Log.i(TAG, "Views " + sumtablelay.getChildCount() + tableLayout1.getChildCount());
            tableLayout1.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            Log.i(TAG, "Pending Views " +  tableLayout1.getChildCount());
        }

        //Create Table Layout and set its default attributes

        tableLayout1.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //add Tablelayout to HScroll
        sumtablelay.addView(tableLayout1);

        //Create Table row and set its default attribute
        TableRow tableRow1 = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //tableRow1.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(tablecolor1));
        //add row to tablelayout
       Log.i(TAG,"Views at Rows "+tableRow1.getChildCount());
       tableRow1.removeAllViews();
        Log.i(TAG,"Pending Views at Rows "+tableRow1.getChildCount());

        tableLayout1.addView(tableRow1);

        //add headings in table row
        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Date");
        textView.setPadding(30, 2, 2, 2);
        textView.setAllCaps(true);
        // textView.setTextColor(textcolorpri);
        textView.setTextSize(15);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        tableRow1.addView(textView);

        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Category");
        textView.setPadding(20, 2, 2, 2);
        textView.setAllCaps(true);
        //  textView.setTextColor(textcolorpri);
        textView.setTextSize(15);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        tableRow1.addView(textView);



        tableRow1.addView(textView);


//Get Data from Table

        Cursor getexpdata = databaseWorking.getalldatatswithcons(PerformanceTweaks.expdata, "pName", pname);
        while (getexpdata != null && getexpdata.moveToNext()) {
            DataEncap DataEncap = new DataEncap();
            DataEncap.setExpddate(getexpdata.getString(getexpdata.getColumnIndex("dated")));
            DataEncap.setExpcat(getexpdata.getString(getexpdata.getColumnIndex("cate")));

                       tempedata.add(DataEncap);
        }



//Adding Data to above layout table.

        for (int a = 0; a < tempedata.size(); a++) {



            tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            textView.setText(tempedata.get(a).getExpddate());
            //   textView.setWidth(col1);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            // textView.setTextColor(textcolorpri);
            textView.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            tableRow.addView(textView);

            textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            textView.setText(tempedata.get(a).getExpcat());
            //   textView.setWidth(col1);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            // textView.setTextColor(textcolorpri);
            textView.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            tableRow.addView(textView);





                tableLayout1.addView(tableRow, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }
        tablelay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove all view use below method
sumtablelay.removeAllViews();

Comment: if u see I wrote that as first line of method, but no results.

Comment: There was no error in the code, just one silly miss that I did not clear my data list on reload.